# sql or function for British summer time

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please can anyone help with a function or sql script that help to put British Summer Time changes into consideration in date column? You know UK time changes between the end of March and October. Clocks move forward an hour on the second Sunday of March and move back again on the first Sunday of November. Your help will be highly appreciated please

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (date/time stuff are to often far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Daylight Savings time Start and End function in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732896/how-to-create-daylight-savings-time-start-and-end-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is may be similar to what you are wanting,

[How to create Daylight Savings time Start and End function in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732896/how-to-create-daylight-savings-time-start-and-end-function-in-sql-server)

see Jamie F's answer and adjust the code for your given timezone, his code is for the us time system so you will need to run through it and see where differences exist and adjust.

Using the SWITCHOFFSET ( DATETIMEOFFSET, time_zone ) function should help with the changes.

Comment: Thank you Joseph but not exactly what I wanted. Maybe my question was not very clear. I have amended the question just to make it a litter clearer. Thank you