# How to convert a date saved in UTC to Time Zone?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My server save time in LOCAL time not including Time Zones info in dateTime2.
Server is in -7 GMT.
I need to create an SQL which show records but converted at TimeZone for User (+1 GMT).

Let's imagine I have this record
'2014-05-27 01:00:00'
Should be displayed as
'2014-05-27 09:00:00'

Using the following script I am not able to get the result desired.
Could you please point me out the problem?

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 
    SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, 
    '2014-05-27 01:00:00'), 
    DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038744/convert-datetime-column-from-utc-to-local-time-in-select-statement 10s of googling

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it does not work as intended as I should be able to set the time zone in the query... as SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() it is the time for the server not for the User querying the db.

Comment: Please, post the output of the script after execution to give you more reasonable answer. By the way, your code works fine for me: if admit the date '2014-05-27 01:00:00' as a UTC date, the script returns '2014-05-27 05:00:00' (+4 GMT) which is correct for my location.

Comment: Is the datetime in your database in your servers local time and not in UTC, ie it should be 08:00 UTC but instead its saved in GMT-7 (01:00)? And you want it to display GTM+1 09:00?

Comment: time in the db is saved at LOCAL time for the server, I need to show it  as GMT +1. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: How about DST? Will you update the code twice a year? Saving LOCAL is always a bad idea, always stick to UTC in the storage, render local in presentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace DATENAME() with a hard-coded '+01:00' value. Keep in mind that using the TZOffset functionality in SQL Server is not yet DST aware, so there will be discrepancies near DST switch over events in March and October.