# SQL Server query (view) Convert String to DateTime

Tags: sql-server, string, datetime, view

I'm a bit rusty and seem to have completely forgot how to do this. I am receiving data and the datatime column is in string format `char(12)`.

Example : `201411061900`

How would I write the query (view) to convert that to `DateTime`?

I've used `CONVERT (datetime, dbo.KWH.mr_dtm,120)`, but I get the error `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

I haven't had much luck. Thank you very much in advance.

If you want to suggest -5 time zone also, I wouldn't mind. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Magnus](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/magnus%20(mm8)/?ws=usercard-mini) answered my question. I wanted to post it here incase it helps anyone in the future.
[Here is the link to the answer.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3c5611fe-781d-4053-9faf-013fb47a54ea/sql-server-query-view-convert-string-to-datetime?forum=csharpgeneral)

There is no output format identifier (like for example 120) that lets you convert a char(12) into a datetime in SQL Server. But you could use the Substring function:

```
Select Cast(Substring(dbo.KWH.mr_dtm,1,8) + ' ' + Substring(dbo.KWH.mr_dtm,9,2)+':'+ Substring(dbo.KWH.mr_dtm,11,2) as DateTime)
```

Thank you to everyone! It is very much appreciated.
Oh, and this post help me solve my timezone setup.

[Convert Datetime column from UTC to local time in select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038744/convert-datetime-column-from-utc-to-local-time-in-select-statement)

Many thanks to [Michael Goldshteyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/473798/michael-goldshteyn) for the timezone convert.