# Convert Local Time to UTC in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you help me on how to convert local time to **UTC** in SQL Server?

I know there is equivalent to C# but what I need is in SQL Server. The timezone is `PACIFIC STANDARD TIME`.

For example:

```
Local Time: "2015-02-02 15:34:23"

UTC: "2015-02-02 23:34:23"
```

Thank you!

I know it's been asked but it's in SQL Server 2008. What I need is in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Will try first.

Comment: do you want to convert it in a select query ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need to do.

Comment: Please take note, I'm dealing with SQL Server 2005.

Comment: My answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038744/convert-datetime-column-from-utc-to-local-time-in-select-statement/57710501#57710501 may help you