# UTC time to Local Time Zone(Central Time) Conversion MS SQL Sever

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-server-2012, timezone

This question is a follow up from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038744/convert-datetime-column-from-utc-to-local-time-in-select-statement). 
I have a UTC time column and I want convert to into current local time `(Central Time Zone or America/Chicago)`. I tried to use the function from @Ron Smith's answer, which is `[dbo].[fn_UTC_to_DST]` function.

In that function, it needs two arguments such as UTC time and offset. I input both like this,

```
SELECT  dbo.fn_UTC_to_DST([time(UTC)],5) as Date
FROM tbl
```

Since we are in Day Light Saving time, I am using 5 as my offset. My output looks like this,

```
2017-09-27 20:55:00.000
2017-09-27 20:56:00.000
2017-09-27 20:57:00.000
2017-09-27 20:58:00.000
...
```

Which should be (central time),

```
2017-09-27 09:55:00.000
2017-09-27 09:56:00.000
2017-09-27 09:57:00.000
2017-09-27 09:58:00.000
...
```

So, I changed @Ron Smith's function like this,

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_UTC_to_DST]
(
    @UTC datetime,
    @StandardOffset int
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
declare 
    @DST datetime,
    @SSM datetime, -- Second Sunday in March
    @FSN datetime  -- First Sunday in November

-- get DST Range
set @SSM = datename(year,@UTC) + '0314' 
set @SSM = dateadd(hour,-5,dateadd(day,datepart(dw,@SSM)*-1+1,@SSM))  -- Changed from 2 to -5
set @FSN = datename(year,@UTC) + '1107'
set @FSN = dateadd(second,-6,dateadd(hour,2,dateadd(day,datepart(dw,@FSN)*-1+1,@FSN)))  -- changed from 1 to -6 

-- add an hour to @StandardOffset if @UTC is in DST range
if @UTC between @SSM and @FSN
    set @StandardOffset = @StandardOffset + 1

-- convert to DST
set @DST = dateadd(hour,@StandardOffset,@UTC)

-- return converted datetime
return @DST

END

GO
```

However, this still gives me the same result as above. 
1. What should I change for Central time?
2. Is there a way to automatically change to -5 during daylight saving time and -6 during standard time?

**EDIT:**

After looking at the Answer and the [reference link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3173/handle-conversion-between-time-zones-in-sql-server--part-1/) from #Siyual,I created the `dbo.TZCalendar` table and I tried to create a function like this (takes one argument and returns a date from refrence link)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConvertUTCToLocal
(
  @utc DATETIME
)
RETURNS Datetime
AS BEGIN 
  SELECT UTCToLocal = DATEADD(HOUR, CASE 

  -- within Daylight Savings Time
  WHEN @utc >= UTC_DST_Start AND @utc < UTC_DST_End 
  THEN -5 

  -- within Standard Time
  ELSE -6 END, @utc)

FROM dbo.TZCalendar 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,@utc) >= [Year] 
  AND CONVERT(DATE,@utc) < DATEADD(YEAR, 1, [Year])
END
GO
```

This, does not work. The logic seems right for me, but, I just need a function without `SCHEMABINDING` (which is done in the reference link). How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server Specify time in another timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30919935/sql-server-specify-time-in-another-timezone)

Comment: @Siyual thank you for the link. I have a question, in my post as I mentioned (form #Ron's answer), is there a way to automatically do the daylight time savings without have to enter the offset manually?

Comment: The answer linked takes into account DST. You just need to change the `ET` columns to `CT` and change the offsets from `-4` and `-5` to `-5` and `-6`.

Comment: @Siyual thank you! Could you explain what is `SET DATEFIRST 7;
;WITH cte(d,p) AS`? May be, commenting right below your answer would be ideal, however, going through it, I want to understand fully!

Comment: @Siyual I have edited my question, I would appreciate if you could look at it. In your answer, you created a function to get the local time after 2 pm, however, I need a function that takes the UTC time and returns local time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked answer ([Sql Server Specify time in another timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30919935/sql-server-specify-time-in-another-timezone)) will get you most of the way there, but to answer the rest of your question, you'll have to make some modifications.

Firstly, I would create a DST calendar, since the DST start and end dates are something that we can compute:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TZCalendar
(
  Year          Int PRIMARY KEY,
  UTC_DST_Start SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
  UTC_DST_End   SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL
);

SET DATEFIRST 7;

;WITH cte(d,p) AS 
(
  -- all the years from 2000 through 50 years after the current year:
  SELECT TOP (YEAR(GETDATE())-2000+51) DATEADD(YEAR,number,'20000101'),
    CASE WHEN number < 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- year < 2007 = 1, else 0
    FROM [master].dbo.spt_values WHERE [type] = N'P' ORDER BY number
)
INSERT dbo.TZCalendar([Year],UTC_DST_Start,UTC_DST_End)
SELECT Year(d),
 -- First Sunday in April (< 2007) or second Sunday in March (>= 2007):
 DATEADD(HOUR, 7, DATEADD(DAY,(7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,DATEADD(MONTH,2+p,d))+1)%7
    +(7*ABS(p-1)),DATEADD(MONTH,2+p,d))),
 -- Last Sunday in October (< 2007) or first Sunday in November (>= 2007):
 DATEADD(HOUR, 6, DATEADD(DAY,(7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,DATEADD(MONTH,10,d))+1)%7
    -(7*p),DATEADD(MONTH,10,d)))
FROM cte
ORDER BY d;
```

This will generate the DST times from the year 2000 to 2067 (this can be expanded based on your needs).

Next, I would create a function to take a `DATE` in `UTC` and return the value in either `CST` or `CDT`, depending on the time of the year.

```
Create Function dbo.fnConvertUTCToCT(@UTC DateTime)
Returns DateTime
As Begin
    Declare @Offset Int = 0

    Select  @Offset = Case When @UTC Between UTC_DST_Start And UTC_DST_End Then -5 Else -6 End
    From    dbo.TZCalendar
    Where   Year = Year(@UTC)

    Set @UTC = DateAdd(Hour, @Offset, @UTC)

    Return @UTC
End
```

Then you can just call that function with any time specified and get the `CST` or `CDT` translation returned:

```
Select   dbo.fnConvertUTCToCT(GetUTCDate())
```

> 2017-09-27 12:24:26.377

Comment: thank you and it works great now. One quick question, instead of showing 24 hours format, is there a way for 12 hour format. I have been searching, no luck! It's not important by any mean, just was wondering. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jesse Since you're using SQL Server 2012+ you can use [`FORMAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql).  An example would be: `Select Format(GetDate(), N'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt')`.

Comment: that is right, I could not think of it! Awesome! Keep rocking :)

Answer (score 8):

If you're using SQL Server 2016+ (or Azure SQL Database) this is built in:

```
SELECT YourInputDatetimeInUTC AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time'
```

The first one asserts your input is UTC, the second one converts it to US Central time, inclusive of DST when applicable (using a Windows time zone identifier).

However, since you said SQL 2012, I'll recommend my [SQL Server Time Zone Support](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) project, where this is a single operation and uses IANA identifiers:

```
SELECT Tzdb.UtcToLocal(YourInputDatetimeInUTC, 'America/Chicago')
```

Comment: Thank you! Installed SQL server 2016 and created a temp table with different time to see the difference to try your first set of code and works perfect. Good work! I wish I could accept both as answer (OP is in 2012)

Answer (score 0):

**UTC time to Central time including DST adjustments**

This SQL expression converts UTC time to Central Standard time which also adjusts itself for the Day Light Saving Time period.

```
DATEADD(HOUR,datediff(HOUR,[HTMPOSTEDDATETIME] at time zone 'Central Standard Time',[HTMPOSTEDDATETIME]),[HTMPOSTEDDATETIME]) [JNL Posted Date]
```