# Convert UTCDatetime to local datetime with daylight time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert UTCdatetime in to local datetime. I got it but when I set timezone `(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)`, then it shows me 1 hour difference. I want exact time as local time.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Too often dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time. (These products have their own versions...)

Comment: SQL Server 2008 or greter

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038744/convert-datetime-column-from-utc-to-local-time-in-select-statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Datetime column from UTC to local time in select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038744/convert-datetime-column-from-utc-to-local-time-in-select-statement)