# Convert string into date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I'm getting the above error when running this statement in SQL Server:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 'Fri, 15 Jan 2016 17:30:05 GMT')
```

Actually I want to insert same string format in `Datetime` column

Comment: What is the expected result. Do you want to convert to local time

Comment: The format of your current timestamp does not appear to be supported by `CONVERT`, so I think you will need to process it to get the conversion to work.

Comment: actually i want to insert same string format in Datetime column

Comment: Present your data to SQL Server in a form that it can easily process: the  [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Tim Biegeleisen, that string needs to be processed to be converted. In order to convert it you need to strip of the day (`Fri,`) and the `GMT` timezone at the end, for example:

```
DECLARE @date varchar(50) = 'Fri, 15 Jan 2016 17:30:05 GMT'
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(@date, 5, LEN(@date) - 8), 113)
```

This solution does strip the timezone information, have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038744/convert-datetime-column-from-utc-to-local-time-in-select-statement) if you want to convert it back to UTC.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to insert the string `'Fri, 15 Jan 2016 17:30:05 GMT'` into `datetime` column then you need to remove `Fri,` and `GMT` from the string before inserting.

```
SELECT CAST(substring(@str_date,5,len(@str_date)-8) as datetime)
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/4884)