# How to create function to convert IST datetime to CST datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have SQL server table in that date field with IST time, I want to convert that datetime field into CST(Chicago) datetime.
how can I write a function that can convert IST to CST and also manage the daylight saving.

Comment: please look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038744/convert-datetime-column-from-utc-to-local-time-in-select-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [DBO].[UDF_IST] (@FROM_DATE DATETIME)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (
            SELECT CAST(SWITCHOFFSET(TODATETIMEOFFSET(GETDATE(), '+05:30'), '-06:00') AS DATETIME) AS [DATETIME]
            )
END
```

after that u need to check like this

```
SELECT dbo.[UDF_IST](@FROMDATE)
```