# Convert UTC to PST in sql

Tags: sql, timezone, utc

```
select date(s.request_timestamp) dt,
```

is giving me a column of dates and times in utc. I have tried using

```
select from_tz
```

and

```
select convert_tz
```

functions but with no luck. I keep getting an error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Comment: Note that it's generally a bad idea to perform timezone conversion in SQL (on a database server) because that requires keeping a separate timezone database file which must be updated regularly (as different countries regularly update their daylight savings policies, often on an annual basis). Ideally it should be performed as close to the view-layer as possible.

Comment: this is for metabase

Comment: Which "metabase"? There are multiple products with that name.

Comment: I also only need this data to show in PST (as my records are only based off of California, USA)

Comment: You're on version v0.24.2
Built on 2017-06-01
Metabase is a Trademark of Metabase, Incand is built with care in San Francisco, CA

Comment: If it's _that_ [Metabase](http://www.metabase.com/) then it's just the frontend. It uses a regular relational database as its backend. So which DBMS _are_ you using as the backend storage? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I think this link would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038744/convert-datetime-column-from-utc-to-local-time-in-select-statement