# Query to Convert UTC datetime to GMT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I have column having datetime in (2017-11-15 13:01:50.397). I want to convert this **UTC datetime to GMT time format**.

Is there any query to convert or what i have to add or subtract number so that it will show in GMT datetime format

Comment: Can you elaborate on your requirement?  A typical pattern followed is to store _all_ your timestamps in the same timezone, e.g. GMT time.  Then, it is up to the consumer to know how to offset those timestamps.

Comment: What is the difference between GMT and UTC. My understanding is that they are the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Datetime column from UTC to local time in select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038744/convert-datetime-column-from-utc-to-local-time-in-select-statement)

Answer (score 1):

you can try below way

```
 declare @InputUtcDateTime datetime = '2017-11-15 13:01:50.397'

   select @InputUtcDateTime - getutcdate() + getdate()
```