# How to convert datetime fromUTC to local time

Tags: sql, sql-server, timezone, utc, localtime

I apologize if this is super easy, I'm still new to SQL and learning everyday. What I'm trying to do is query

```
SELECT ProjectName,
       RequestNumber,
       ContactId,
       ContactFirstName,
       ContactLastName,
       RequestReceivedDate,
       RequestCloseDate,
       Category,
       SubCategory,
       AssignedResourceId,
       OwningResourceId,
       RequestSource,
       ClosedImmediatelyFlag,
       RequestStatusCode
FROM dbo.system_requests;
```

BUT my RequestReceivedDate and RequestCloseDate, are off by 5 hours. I can't create a function as I'm working with a vendor database so looking to convert UTC to local time in my select statement and just not sure the best way of doing this?

Thoughts?

Comment: What is your db system? Oracle?

Comment: db system would be SQL

Comment: SQL is used everywhere in any RDBMS system, such as Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, Sybase, etc. So you are not answering my question.

Comment: Hey sorry, again super new and still very much learning so my apologizes but it's SQL Server 2017

Comment: You may check this link:
[Convert Datetime column from UTC to local time in select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038744/convert-datetime-column-from-utc-to-local-time-in-select-statement)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2016 has support for time zones with the AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' statement. You can do this:

```
SELECT ProjectName,
       RequestNumber,
       ContactId,
       ContactFirstName,
       ContactLastName,
       RequestReceivedDate AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
       RequestCloseDate AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
       Category,
       SubCategory,
       AssignedResourceId,
       OwningResourceId,
       RequestSource,
       ClosedImmediatelyFlag,
       RequestStatusCode
FROM dbo.system_requests;
```

You can search for "AT TIME ZONE" on Google.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up doing this and it worked and gave me what i wanted:

```
           SELECT CONVERT(
                             DATETIME,
                             SWITCHOFFSET(
                                             CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, system_requests.RequestReceivedDate),
                                             DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
                                         )
                         ) AS RequestReceivedDate
       ),
       (
           SELECT CONVERT(
                             DATETIME,
                             SWITCHOFFSET(
                                             CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, system_requests.RequestCloseDate),
                                             DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
                                       )
                         ) AS RequestClosedDate
```