# In SQL Server 2014 , how to convert given UTC date time to PST date time, when the server is in UTC

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, utc

How to convert given UTC date time to PST date time, by keeping the daylight stuff in time calculations?

Note that the server I am hitting is in utc. I mean, `GETDATE() = GETUTCDATE()`.

Also, we can't use `AT TIME ZONE`, as DB is on older SQL Server.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What version of SQL exactly? What makes you think we can suggest correct syntax if we don't know what version you are on?

Comment: sorry it was sql server 2014

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Datetime column from UTC to local time in select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038744/convert-datetime-column-from-utc-to-local-time-in-select-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search the site, example: [Convert Datetime column from UTC to local time in select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038744/convert-datetime-column-from-utc-to-local-time-in-select-statement)

Read the link above, also include daylight stuff in there for some of the responses too.

Comment: copied the query from @Aiden Kaskela : select CONVERT(datetime, SWITCHOFFSET(yourdate, DATEPART(TZOFFSET, yourdate AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time')))