# Update Query in SQL Server for Datetime zone

Tags: sql-server

I have Table called Print_Service in that  i have to update column name called Service_Date with values which has date time in UTC time Zone in SQL Server 2012(backend).
in order to see correct date in Frontend Application i need to change it in PAcific Std time that is UTC-7.
how to use update query for that?

Comment: PDT is UTC-7, not PST. PDT could be calculated as DATEADD(hour,-7,Service_Date), but will not provide the correct time when the UTC value is during standard time observance. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038744/convert-datetime-column-from-utc-to-local-time-in-select-statement).

Comment: update Print_Service set Service_Date ='2007-07-23' from Print_Service ps inner join Service_Price sp on ps.CustomerUniqueId = sp.UniqueID Where sp.UniqueID = 'Jter-qw12-2300-h323''

Comment: Could you make this adjustment in your application taking into account if we are in Daylight Saving or Standard Time?