# How to convert UTC datetime values stored as a VARCHAR to a regular datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, amazon-redshift, sqldatatypes

I have this date `'2021-04-22T17:06:59.391Z'` stored in UTC datetime, but the column datatype is `VARCHAR`. How do I convert this to a regular datetime with column datatype `date` ?

- Existing column (type `VARCHAR`) - `2021-04-22T17:06:59.391Z`
- Expected output (type `DATE`) - `2021-04-22 17:06:59`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Datetime column from UTC to local time in select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038744/convert-datetime-column-from-utc-to-local-time-in-select-statement)

Comment: @brad  this did not work for me for some reason.

Comment: @jarlh I am using SQL Workbench/J connected to a redshift cluster.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Dates in Redshift don't have a time component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the expected result.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(0), CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,'2021-04-22T17:06:59.391Z'))
```

Comment: Could you please share the error  screen ?

Comment: Invalid operation: syntax error at end of input 
Position: 8; [SQL State=42601, DB Errorcode=500310]
1 statement failed.