# SQL Server UTC to Local time 'at time zone' not offseting time

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to convert from UTC to Eastern Standard Time. But the code below  is not producing the result that I expect.

```
SELECT 
    GETUTCDATE() AS UTC_Date,  --original datetime value
    GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' AS ETZ
```

The result is

```
UTC_Date = 2022-01-16 01:15:39.920
ETZ =2022-01-16 01:15:39.920 -05:00
```

How can I get a simple date time with the offset applied instead of just added on to the end of the string?

Comment: ok, thanks that worked.

Comment: @lptr You've been asked this already: if you have an answer please post an answer instead of a comment. You can always make it a community wiki if you don't want it associated with you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Datetime column from UTC to local time in select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038744/convert-datetime-column-from-utc-to-local-time-in-select-statement) Second answer there uses the above syntax for SQL Server 2016+

Comment: yes it does.....