# How to convert from UTC to EST in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, time, utc

I am currently using:

```
sample_start_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' AS sample_start_time_est
```

from:
[Convert Datetime column from UTC to local time in select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038744/convert-datetime-column-from-utc-to-local-time-in-select-statement)

```
sample_start_time
2021-03-10 21:13:00.000
```

becomes

```
sample_start_time_est
2021-03-10 16:13:00.000 -05:00
```

Though EST is now displayed, I think the system still recognizes it as UTC based on the results of subsequent queries. How do I get the system to recognize the adjusted time as EST?

For instance:

```
sample_start_time_est = 2021-03-10 16:14:00.000 -05:00
end_time = 2021-03-10 18:14:00.000
WHERE sample_start_time_est < end_time
```

above WHERE clause currently evaluates to FALSE but I want it to be TRUE

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Are these columns `datetimeoffset`?

Comment: the datatype is currently DATETIME. I need to change it to DATETIMEOFFSET?

Comment: You want a time in Zone A to be greater than a time in Zone UTC when Zone A's local  time, converted  to UTC, would be greater than Zone UTC's local time, correct?

Comment: @RossBush I think that's correct. Basically, one approach would be to subtract 4 hours from times that are originally in UTC, but then this would neglect daylight savings. I want DST to be accounted for.

Comment: Since 2014 Time zone info has been implemented in Sql Server. The general way of doing this is to convert all dates to a UTC, using the TimeZoneInfo functions, which account for various windows of dst, then do your math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CAST(sample_start_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' AS DATETIME2) AS sample_start_time_est
```

Answer (score 0):

The result you are seeing is happening because `datetimeoffset` has a higher precedence than `datetime`, and your comparison will force an implicit conversion. The implicit conversion will turn a `datetime` into a `datetimeoffset` with zero offset:

```sql
declare @dto_minus5 datetimeoffset = '2022-01-01 00:00:00 -05:00'
declare @later_dt datetime = '2022-01-01 01:00:00'; -- 1 hour later *if* we ignore the offset
declare @later_dt_casted datetimeoffset = cast(@later_dt as datetimeoffset);

select @dto_minus5, @later_dt_casted, iif(@dto_minus5 < @later_dt, 1, 0);

-- produces 2022-01-01 00:00:00 -05:00  2022-01-01 01:00:00 +00:00  0
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=93b523b5216f9f357a31a5bbe73dcf99);

What happens in the `iif` is that `@later_dt` gets promoted to `datetimeoffset`, with an offset of 0. When these are then compared, the offset is taken into account. That is to say, the two values are "brought into the same time zone". That means my `@dto_minus5` value gets 5 hours added to it (or equivalently, the `@later_dt` gets 5 hours subtracted).

That is to say, the comparison of:

`2022-01-01 00:00:00 -05:00` vs `2022-01-01 01:00:00`

becomes a comparison of:

`2022-01-01 00:00:00 -05:00` vs `2022-01-01 01:00:00 +00:00`

Which in the same time zone is a comparison of:

`2022-01-01 05:00:00 +00:00` vs `2022-01-01 01:00:00 +00:00`

So the former is larger.

To get the semantics you want, you can use the `todatetimeoffset()` function:

```sql
declare @sample_start_time_est datetimeoffset = '2021-03-10 16:14:00.000 -05:00';
declare @end_time datetime = '2021-03-10 18:14:00.000';

select iif(@sample_start_time_est < todatetimeoffset(@end_time, '-05:00'), 1, 0);

-- prints 1
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, your solution will not take into account daylight savings since you are subtracting 5 hours. I have thousands of values and cannot manually adjust this to be 4 or 5 for all values.

Comment: @Mattpats It's not quite that I'm subtracting 5 hours, it's that I'm specifying what offset I want to apply. You can also just do to the `end_time` value what you did to the `sample_start_time`. Either way, what you *can't* do is just compare a datetime to a datetimeoffset and get the semantics you're after. But if the existing data is a datetime it is not specifying anything about daylight savings, and there's no way for SQL to "just know" whether any particular value should be interpreted as DST or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SWITCHOFFSET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/switchoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to convert from UTC to EST like this:

```sql
SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, sample_start_time ), '-05:00')
```

**Note**: If your column is not already a `datetimeoffset`, you can [`CAST` or `CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) it before passing ot switch offset