# SQL Server CLR Functions supported in AppHarbor?

Tags: sql-server, appharbor

I think I know the answer is NO, but wanted to confirm:

**Are [CLR functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189524.aspx) supported in AppHarbor's shared SQL Server environments?**

*This question came from a [proposed solution to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634129/best-practices-for-storing-user-time-zone-tsql-net#comment15409756_11634129).*

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't just ask AppHarbor?

Comment: @Pondlife - Yes, because their support site says "If you have a general question about how to make your application run on AppHarbor, posting it on Stack Overflow will get you accurate answers fast."

Comment: Interesting, so they've crowdsourced their support

Comment: We're happy to field questions through other channels also, but Stackoverflow is awesome because it makes existing answers easily discoverable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shared SQL engines (yocto, nano) do not support CLR. Appharbor recommends that you "[move the relevant logic into your application code](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/2181-clr-integration-for-sql-server)" and I tend to agree.

You can get a [dedicated MSSQL](https://appharbor.com/applications/haystack/addons/dedicatedsqlserver) instance on Amazon EC2 *through* Appharbor; that may permit you to enable CLR.